# Why are these SATA bus ports different?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

I bought several larger 3.5" HDDs in SATA format and two of them have a different port on them and will not mate with the external enclosure.

One of them is a 3TB and the other is a 6 TB. The 6TB is a Seagate and is an "Enterprise Capacity" with no other instructions on it.

I can't imagine the capacity making any difference but all my 4TB HDDs have the matching port to my external enclosure.

There is supposed to be a slot keyway between the power side of the port and the data side, for the HDD to slide all the way into the port but these two have a piece of hard plastic molded into the port to prevent that.

What is different about these drives that would require this?

Comment: Could you include pictures of the connectors, or at least describe them (shape, number of pins...)?

Answer (score 44):

If you got "enterprise" drives then they are probably SAS ([Serial Attached SCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI)) and not SATA ([Serial ATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA)). They use incredibly similar connectors and a SAS host can connect to SATA drives, but a SATA host cannot connect to SAS drives. The connectors are nearly the same with the exception of an extra piece of plastic between the two SATA connector halves that prevent a SAS drive being plugged into a SATA host.

If you have bought SAS drives and only have a SATA controller then you should return the drives.

From Seagate: [Connecting SATA drive to SAS controller](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/connecting-sata-drive-to-sas-controller-006170en/)

> [image]
> [image]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI) (emphasis mine)

> There is little physical difference between SAS and SATA.
>
> - SAS protocol provides for multiple initiators in a SAS domain, while SATA has no analogous provision.
> - Most SAS drives provide tagged command queuing, while most newer SATA drives provide native command queuing.
> - **SATA uses a command set that is based on the parallel ATA command set** and then extended beyond that set to include features like native command queuing, hot-plugging, and TRIM. **SAS uses the SCSI command set, which includes a wider range of features** like error recovery, reservations and block reclamation. Basic ATA has commands only for direct-access storage. However SCSI commands may be tunnelled through ATAPI for devices such as CD/DVD drives.
> - SAS hardware allows multipath I/O to devices while SATA (prior to SATA 2.0) does not. Per specification, SATA 2.0 makes use of port multipliers to achieve port expansion, and some port multiplier manufacturers have implemented multipath I/O using port multiplier hardware.
> - SATA is marketed as a general-purpose successor to parallel ATA and has become common in the consumer market, whereas the more-expensive SAS targets critical server applications.
> - SAS error-recovery and error-reporting uses SCSI commands, which have more functionality than the ATA SMART commands used by SATA drives.
> - **SAS uses higher signaling voltages (800–1,600 mV for transmit, and 275–1,600 mV for receive) than SATA (400–600 mV for transmit, and 325–600 mV for receive)**. The higher voltage offers (among other features) the ability to use SAS in server backplanes.
> - Because of its higher signaling voltages, SAS can use cables up to 10 m (33 ft) long, whereas SATA has a cable-length limit of 1 m (3.3 ft) or 2 m (6.6 ft) for eSATA.
> - SAS is full duplex, whereas SATA is half duplex. The SAS transport layer can transmit data at the full speed of the link in both directions at once, so a SCSI command executing over the link can transfer data to and from the device simultaneously. However, because SCSI commands that can do that are rare, and a SAS link must be dedicated to an individual command at a time, this is generally not an advantage with a single device.

Comment: Alternatively, purchase a PCIe SAS controller - you may be able to pick one up under 50USD

Comment: @Bravo, that will not make a SAS drive fit into an external SATA enclosure.

Comment: @StarCat ahh, I missed that bit

Comment: Also SAS have a few more pins behind the "moulded part".

Comment: SAS drives tend to be worth more than SATA drives, so reselling might be more profitable than returning them.   However you can't test them.

Comment: I see that technology has sped right by me and not even honked the horn! I have never heard of a SAS drive although I certainly started on the SCSI buses that came with Macs. #Mokubai, thank you for bringing that to my knowledge. In hindsight it would have been nice if the eBay seller had mentioned that in his ad. I'm sorry I'm late in responding to your efforts on my behalf but I was expecting to be notified of an answer by email. So I'm late finding this. This is also my first use of SuperUser. Thanks to all that responded.